# Anti-slip foam material used for shoulder-rest?

Tags: violin, lutherie, ergonomics

What's the name of the very anti-slip foam felt used in popular violin shoulder rests such as Everest, Bonmusica etc?

I have a high neck and I want to cut out another layer of that foam to adhere to the shoulder rest.
Additionally, I want to experiment more options with foam to make my playing easier and more convenient.

Comment: You could contact the company and ask.  Also I think the manufacturer of the wonderful thing you can put on the chin rest, I forget what it's called, is nice and will talk with you about the materials and production process.  You could also experiment with a foam pad (such as Suzuki students often use), a big cleaning sponge (you can trim it with scissors and patience), and moleskin (drugstore, foot care aisle).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend instead inserting a solid spacer between the existing foam pad and the base of the shoulder rest.  You really don't want a thick "squishy" pad as that will tend to change thickness as you move while playing (not to mention collapsing over time as the material ages).   Another alternative is to use any kind of spacer and put a layer of the thin "fishnet" anti-slip rug pad material you can get most anywhere.

However, I'm concerned about your posture in the first place. If you have the violin properly positioned, the shoulder rest should not be prone to slipping.  You may want to have someone evaluate your overall positioning of the violin relative to your chin and shoulder.